# react-redux dispatch action does not work on android but works on ios

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have set up my store correctly and everything works perfectly fine on ios. But on android with the exact same code, the dispatch action has no effect, it does not populate my context with the value returned from my APi.

Since it is exactly the same code, I have been struggling to figure out what the issue could be.

I am using

```
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
```

calling the action on app launch

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const trans = useSelector(state => state.translation);
useEffect(() => {
    fetchTranslations(dispatch)
  }, [])
```

reducer

```
import React from "react";

const initState = {};

const TranslationReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_TRANSLATIONS':
      return action.payload.data
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default TranslationReducer
```

action

```
import { get } from '../api/query';

export function fetchTranslations(dispatch) {
  try {
    return (
      get('/api/v3/labels/mobile_app/')
      .then(res => {
        console.log('res', res)
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log('response', response)
        dispatch({
          type: 'FETCH_TRANSLATIONS',
          payload: response
        })
      })
    )
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error', e)
  }
}
```

everything is correctly returned from the api, but dispatching the action does nothing to the state, it stays empty on android, but works fine on ios.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after many days of searching, I went back into the setting up of redux-devtoools and changed a line in the initialisation of my store.

before

```
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    {},
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))
  );
```

**solution**

```
  const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    {},
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  );
```

this is the line that seemed to be causing the error on Android only
`composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))`

I have yet to understand why, but for everyone going through a similar error, I hope this will be useful.